# Checking all rank is true without using mpi4py gather and scatter

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to communicate between processes so that every processes are notified when all other processes are ready. The code snippet below does that. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
def get_all_ready_status(ready_batch):
    all_ready= all(ready_batch)
    return [all_ready for _ in ready_batch]

ready_batch= comm.gather(ready_agent, root=0)
if rank == 0:
    all_ready_batch = get_all_ready_status(ready_batch)
all_ready_flag = comm.scatter(all_ready_batch , root=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the processes need to be aware which other processes are ready then you can use the `comm.Allgather` routine:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

sendBuffer = numpy.ones(1, dtype=bool)
recvBuffer = numpy.zeros(size, dtype=bool)

print("Before Allgather => Process %s | sendBuffer %s | recvBuffer %s" % (rank, sendBuffer, recvBuffer))
comm.Allgather([sendBuffer,  MPI.BOOL],[recvBuffer, MPI.BOOL])
print("After Allgather  => Process %s | sendBuffer %s | recvBuffer %s" % (rank, sendBuffer, recvBuffer))
```

**Output:**

```
Before Allgather => Process 0 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [False False]
Before Allgather => Process 1 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [False False]
After Allgather  => Process 0 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [ True  True]
After Allgather  => Process 1 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [ True  True]
```

As pointed out in the comments by  @Gilles Gouaillardet:

> if all processes only have to know if all processes are ready, then
> MPI_Allreduce() is an even better fit.

The idea is that in theory [Allreduce](https://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/collectiveCom.html) should be faster then `Allgather`
because the former can use a tree communication pattern and because it will require to allocate and communicate less memory. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012643/performance-of-mpi-reduce-vs-mpi-gather-reduction-on-root).

In your case, you use `MPI.LAND` (i.e., logical and) as the Allreduce operation operator.

An example:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

sendBuffer =  numpy.ones(1, dtype=bool) if rank % 2 ==  0 else numpy.zeros(1, dtype=bool)
recvBuffer = numpy.zeros(1, dtype=bool)

print("Before Allreduce => Process %s | sendBuffer %s | recvBuffer %s" % (rank, sendBuffer, recvBuffer))
comm.Allreduce([sendBuffer,  MPI.BOOL],[recvBuffer, MPI.BOOL], MPI.LAND)
print("After Allreduce  => Process %s | sendBuffer %s | recvBuffer %s" % (rank, sendBuffer, recvBuffer))

comm.Barrier()
if rank == 0:
   print("Second RUN")
comm.Barrier()

sendBuffer =  numpy.ones(1, dtype=bool)
recvBuffer = numpy.zeros(1, dtype=bool)

print("Before Allreduce => Process %s | sendBuffer %s | recvBuffer %s" % (rank, sendBuffer, recvBuffer))
comm.Allreduce([sendBuffer,  MPI.BOOL],[recvBuffer, MPI.BOOL], MPI.LAND)
print("After Allreduce  => Process %s | sendBuffer %s | recvBuffer %s" % (rank, sendBuffer, recvBuffer))
```

**The Output:**

```
Before Allreduce => Process 1 | sendBuffer [False] | recvBuffer [False]
Before Allreduce => Process 0 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [False]
After Allreduce  => Process 1 | sendBuffer [False] | recvBuffer [False]
After Allreduce  => Process 0 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [False]
Second RUN
Before Allreduce => Process 0 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [False]
Before Allreduce => Process 1 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [False]
After Allreduce  => Process 0 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [ True]
After Allreduce  => Process 1 | sendBuffer [ True] | recvBuffer [ True]
```

In the first part of the output (*i.e.,* before "Second RUN"), the result is `FALSE` because the processes with even rank where not ready (i.e., `False`) and the processes with odd rank where ready. Hence, `False & True =>  False`. In the second part, the result is `True` because all processes were ready.